# Cloudflare Worker GeoIP redirect with match URL and Fallback

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am following along with this template: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/country-code-redirect

Essentially, I’d like to redirect the root domain as well as match the URL slug.

Example:

domain.com => en.domain.com

domain.com/some-page => en.domain.com/some-page

I am also trying to set a fallback URL in the event a country code does not match, this way any country codes I don't set will be redirected to en.domain.com. I plan to map many different country codes to their respective language URL.

Need to have US and other English speaking countries route to en.domain.com and then other languages/countries set to their respective subdomain path. Here's sort of what I was working towards, but not getting it correctly:

```js
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(handleRequest(event));
});


const handleRequest = async (event) => {
    
    const {request} = event
    const country = request.cf.country
    const url = new URL(request.url)
    const {hostname, pathname, protocol} = url
    
    const countryMap = {
        US: 'en',
        FR: 'fr',
        ES: 'es',
        PA: 'es'
    }
        
    if(country)
    {
        const lang = countryMap.hasOwnProperty(country) ? countryMap[country] : 'en'
        const newHostName = `${lang === 'en' ? '' : lang + '.'}${hostname}`
        
        //en = example.com
        //fr = fr.example.com
        //es = es.example.com
        //pa = es.example.com
        
        if(hostname !== newHostName)
        {
            const redirectUrl = new URL(pathname, `${protocol}//${newHostName}${pathname}`)
            
            return Response.redirect(redirectUrl.href, 301)
        }
        
    }
    
    return await fetch(request)
}
```

Any help with getting this accomplished would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to check if you managed to get it working with the code I provided? Please mark as answer if it satisfies your requirements. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if this works for you?

I've tried it on my end and it satisfies your requirements.

```javascript
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})


async function handleRequest(request) {
    const country = request.headers.get('cf-ipcountry')

    // Define redirections
    const languageRules = new Map([
        ["ES", 'es'],
        ["PA", 'es'],
        ["FR", 'fr']
    ])
    
    //Get value from key
    const languageCode = languageRules.get(country)

    // Redirect to language subdomain for custom countries set
    if (languageCode) {
        const root = ".domain.com"
        const url = new URL(request.url)
        const path = url.pathname
        const protocol = url.protocol
        const destinationDomain = protocol + "//" + languageCode + root + path
        return Response.redirect(destinationDomain, 301)
    }        
    
    // Redirect to english domain for any other country
    else {
        const root = "en.domain.com"
        const url = new URL(request.url)
        const path = url.pathname;
        const protocol = url.protocol
        const destinationDomain = protocol + "//" + root + path
        return Response.redirect(destinationDomain, 301)
    }

    // Process request and return response
    const response = await fetch(request)
    return response
}
```